# Importing repositories into Apache Archiva

Tags: apache, archiva

I have an existing version (pretty old) of Apache Archiva running with a couple of repositories which are holding my JARs.
Now, I have setup a new installation of the latest version of Archiva on a separate system and I want to import all those repositories from the old installation to this new one. I cannot see any import option available on the Archiva GUI.

Can anyone suggest me a method with which I can mass import all the repositories between the two installations.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy repositories directories from previous instance to the new one.
And that's it :-)